# How to get a controller of API project from UI project with DispatchProxy in ASP.NET CORE

Tags: c#, reflection, proxy, asp.net-core, dispatch

I have some projects in my solution, for example UI and API.

I want to create a controller instance from the API project in my UI project without adding a reference from the UI project to the the API project.

Like this:

```
public T CreateProxy<T>()
{
     // There is a code like this. I don't know how to use it.
     // I researched it, but I couldn't get enough info.
     var proxy = System.Reflection.DispatchProxy.Create<T, TProxy>();
     return proxy;
}
```

UI controller:

```
IParameterApi = CreateProxy<IParameterApi>();

// ParameterController is coming from API.
//( i dont know how to map it. dependency injection or what ? )

// and I've got this controllers Add, Update, Remove and more methods that I can use.
```

How can i do this???